# Goの日付変換処理

Tags: go

Goのtime.Time型の日時をフォーマットして元の変数に代入するようにしたのですが、変換されません。

```
hoge.CreatedAt, err = time.Parse("2006年1月2日15時4分", hoge.CreatedAt.Format("2006年1月2日15時4分"))
```

ここで`hoge.CreatedAt`を表示しても変換前のままです。
変換前の日付
`2015-09-01 08:12:00 +0000 UTC`

なぜ変換されないのでしょうか。

Comment: hoge.CreatedAt は time.Time 型で文字列データではなく、時刻表記のフォーマットを変更しても内部データは変化しません(同じ時刻であれば)。なので、フォーマットを変更する場合は新たに string 型の変数を用意して、`str := hoge.CreatedAt.Format("2006年1月2日15時4分")` などとする必要があります。

Comment: それは上記コードと同じではないですか｡

Comment: はい、そうです。ただ、hoge.CreatedAt の内部データ(時刻データ)は変化しません。また、時刻データ(time.Time型変数の中身)は文字列ではありませんし、フォーマット情報は含まれていません。そのため、`Format()` メソッドを使って、指定したフォーマットで表記される**日時・時刻文字列**を随時取得する必要があるのです。

Comment: `time.Time`型への再代入は不可能ということですか｡

Comment: 再代入は可能なのですが、、、同じ値(同じ時刻データ)を代入することになります。`fmt.Printf("%#v\n", hoge.CreatedAt)` を実行して、time.Time型変数の中身を確認してみて下さい。

Comment: あ､やっとわかりました｡time.Time型に違う形の時刻データを入れられないということですか｡納得しました｡ありがとうございます｡

Answer (score 0):

`hoge.CreatedAt`は`time.Time型`で文字列データではなく、時刻表記のフォーマットを変更しても内部データは変化しません(同じ時刻であれば)。
なので、フォーマットを変更する場合は新たに`string型`の変数を用意して、`str := hoge.CreatedAt.Format("2006年1月2日15時4分")` などとする必要があります。

また、時刻データ(time.Time型変数の中身)は文字列ではありませんし、フォーマット情報は含まれていません。
そのため、(文字列を取得する場合は)`Format()`メソッドを使って、指定したフォーマットで表記される**日時・時刻文字列**を随時取得する必要があるのです。

---

<sup>この投稿は @user9156 さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/15107/go%e3%81%ae%e6%97%a5%e4%bb%98%e5%a4%89%e6%8f%9b%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86#comment13716_15107)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>